# How to modify dataClass.mustache and corresponding swagger.yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mustache, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

I want to generate model classes in kotlin-spring.
I have a specific structure defined for which I want to generate the data classes using mustache template and swagger file.

```
data class Student (
val age,
val id
) : StudentSection (
val sectionName,
val sectionId
) {

}
```

I want to modify dataClass.mustache and write a swagger file to generate data class as given above.
Please suggest.

I tried it with modifying the dataClass.mustache template but somehow its not generating it properly.